# Reading from `forkpty` child process: `ls /` output yields `EIO`

Tags: c, ipc, execvp, pty

I'm trying to use `forkpty` to `execvp` a `ls /`, and then from the parent process read its output and write to stdout.

I got it working, and running it under Valgrind shows no errors either.

EDIT: Valgrind shows no memory errors. The last `read` still yields `EIO` under Valgrind.

However, the last `read` always returns `-1` and sets `errno` to `EIO`. I've been researching and reading the manual pages, but I still don't understand exactly why that happens:

> ```
>   EIO    I/O  error.  This will happen for example when the process is in
>          a background process group, tries to read from  its  controlling
>          terminal,  and  either it is ignoring or blocking SIGTTIN or its
>          process group is orphaned.  It may also occur when  there  is  a
>          low-level I/O error while reading from a disk or tape.
> ```

I've also noticed that if I catch `SIGCHLD` signals I can know when `ls` has exited, but if I list a bigger directory such as `/usr/bin` then I get that signal for the `ls` child process even when there are many `read`s following that succeed.

Here's an example output:

```
$ ./a.out
bin    dev         initrd.img.old  libx32      opt   sbin  usr
boot   etc         lib             lost+found  proc  srv   var
build  home        lib32           media       root  sys   vmlinuz
core   initrd.img  lib64           mnt         run   tmp   vmlinuz.old
# read: Input/output error
```

Am I missing something obvious?

```
#include <pty.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int master_fd;
    pid_t child_pid = forkpty(&master_fd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (child_pid == -1) {
        perror("# forkpty");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else if (!child_pid) { /* CHILD */
        char* ls_argv[] = {
            "ls",
            "/",
            NULL,
        };

        execvp(ls_argv[0], ls_argv);
        perror("# execvp");
        abort();
    }
    else { /* PARENT */
        uint8_t buffer[BUFSIZ];
        ssize_t read_count;

        while ((read_count = read(master_fd, buffer, BUFSIZ)) > 0) {
            uint8_t* ptr = buffer;
            size_t ptr_len = (size_t) read_count;

            while (ptr_len > 0) {
                ssize_t write_count = write(STDOUT_FILENO, ptr, ptr_len);

                if (write_count == -1) {
                    perror("# write");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }

                ptr += write_count;
                ptr_len -= write_count;
            }
        }

        if (read_count == -1) {
            perror("# read");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if (close(master_fd) == -1) {
            perror("# close");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        int child_status;

        if (waitpid(child_pid, &child_status, 0) == -1) {
            perror("# waitpid");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if (!WIFEXITED(child_status)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "# main: subprocess did not exit normally\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        return child_status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be three parts to the question:

a) Is EIO a valid error in this case (on the last read)?

b) Why is a SIGCHLD being received much ahead of the expected I/O completion,

c) Why doesn't the error happen with Valgrind?

a) The last read is expected to fail since the read is similar to the one on a broken pipe with the child process having exited. EOF seems to be a more meaningful error as compared to EIO.( It may also occur when  there  is  a      low-level I/O error while reading from a disk or tape.)

b) The CPU processing being much ahead of I/O caused this. Having received the SIGCHLD (and having set a flag to indicate the child has exited) the parent process should be expecting the read to fail once it's done reading information that the child wrote into the slave-pty and hence safely ignore the EIO.

c) I am not sure about this. While Valgrind might have slowed up things a bit giving enough time for I/O processing the final read would still be expected to fail (return -1), in this case with EIO.

Comment: c) I should've been more clear. I've updated my question. (Valgrind shows no *memory* errors.)

Comment: a) So what you're saying is that since `read` doesn't set `errno` to `EPIPE` (which is what I would expect in a situation with a broken pipe), then it sets it instead to `EIO`?

Comment: EPIPE is reserved for PIPE related errors. Given that pty is a emulation of a tty-to-tty connection, a missing tty on the other end is "possibly" interpreted as an I/O error (Reviewing the pty driver code of the OS you are using would provide more clarity on the error handling)..

Answer (score 1):

The pty driver calls a kernel internal function to invalidate the slave pty side, which returns `EIO` from then on, until the slave side is closed.  This happens always the master side is closed by the controlling process.

This process *is standard in all unix variants today*. It is a workaround to avoid processes to continue using the device after the master side has gone.  Even if you attach the master side again with a new process, the old slave process is blocked until it closes the open descriptor.

Comment: So does that mean in this situation it's acceptable to check for `EIO` and ignore it?

Comment: the condition has been created to be able to detect that the service has finished anyway (the process controlling the master side has closed it, so no sense is in writing or reading it anyway) The best thing you can do with it is to `close(2)` it.  The descriptor is not usable in any useful way after this condition has happened.  It is acceptable to check it for EIO and ignore it.  Be careful, that BSD unix (all flavours) and Linux behave differently in this case, if you want to port your software between them.

Comment: This appears to be describing the situation where the _master_ side of the pty (/dev/ptmx) is closed, but OP is asking about the situation where all processes connected to the _slave_ side have closed their side.

Comment: @zwol exactly, that's the part I don't understand in @luis-colorado answer and from the read(2) manpage, since AFAIK in my example it's the slave side that closes the pty first, and then generates `EIO` for some reason I don't yet know.

Comment: It's possible that the behavior Luis describes is symmetric, but I would have expected your scenario to generate an EOF indication (that is, zero bytes read).

Comment: ... I ran your program (with trivial modifications: `s/pty.h/util.h/`) on a FreeBSD system, and it did *not* receive an EIO after `ls` exited.  It received an EOF, instead. I am starting to think this is a bug in Linux.

Comment: @zwol, it is different behaviour.  Both systems inherit code from different sources.  You can file a bug report, but you'll mostly be answered that it is POSIX compliant (and this **is** the objective of linux, being posix and not UNIX compliant)  I'm afraid you will not have success on your intent, but you are free to go that way.  I discovered that special behaviour of the linux pty driver on driving my [slowtty][https://github.com/mojadita/slowtty.git] program.

Comment: @LuisColorado, do you have a pointer to an official source documenting that behavior?

Comment: @Márcio, nope, I only have the sample code given above, to illustrate the use of ptys.  It runs in linux and freebsd, so I think it covers a spread enough range of architectures.